# displaying page not found error with zend acl

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

whenever a controller is called if it is not registered in zend acl then we ususally get erro r like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 
'Resource 'hsfasfdadsf' not found' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Acl.php:365
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/update/library/Management/Access.php(55): Zend_Acl->get('hsfasfdadsf') 
#1 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php(309): Management_Access->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#2 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Controller/Front.php(941):
```

isn't there a way to check if the controller and action is registered in zend acl, i tried

```
if(!$acl->get($controller))
{
    $request->setControllerName('error');
    $request->setActionName('notfound');
}
```

but did not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### First solution:

Avoid those exceptions, e.g.

```
if (!$acl->has($your_resource)) {
   // .. handle it the way you need
}
```

#### Second one

Handle those exceptions in ErrorController, i.e.:

```
if ($errors->exception instanceof Zend_Acl_Exception) {
    // send needed headers...
    // prepare log message...
    // render info: resource_not_found.phtml
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer('resource_not_found');
}
```

Comment: thanks but $acl->hasResource() is not working, $acl->has() worked! you might wanna edit your code.

Comment: Also you need another closing bracket on your first solution: if (!$acl->has($your_resource))